# Scapy problem in sending packet

Tags: network, network-scanners, python

I am trying to use Scapy for testing the network.

Whenever I send a packet with commands like `send`, `sr` ,`sr1` I get this message:

> python.exe has stopped working

I am using Scapy 2.2.0 on Windows 8.1, Python 2.7.11, Anaconda 2.5.0 (64bit).